# I need to display prime numbers within a range using min. of 1 while & for loop. And getting the wrong output

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeN {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b;
    a = sc.nextInt();
    b = sc.nextInt();
    while (a < b) {
      for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          if (i % j == 0) {
            count++;
          }
        } //count if equals 2 the prime numbers displayed
        if (count == 2) {
          System.out.println(i);
          a++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what my output looks like. I dont understand why last prime numbers are being repeatedly printed.

[image]

Comment: You missplaced your first statement, your while-loop is a little bit scary

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to solve the ques.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b;
    a = sc.nextInt();
    b = sc.nextInt();
   for(int n = a; n <= b; n++){
     boolean prime = true;
     int i = 2; //1 will be a factor always
     while(i <= n/2){
        if(n%i == 0){
        //is not prime
        prime = false;
        break;
      }i++;
     }
   if(prime){
    System.out.print(n+ " ");
   }
 }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your while(a<b) around the two for loops and then your code works fine

like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeN {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b;
        a = sc.nextInt();
        b = sc.nextInt();
        // System.out.println("a<b");
        int i = a;
        while(i<=b)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            } // count if equals 2 the prime numbers displayed
            if (count == 2) {
                System.out.println("a" + a + " i:" + i);
                a++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

To find out what the actual error is, print out the values of a,b,i and j in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks:).But the test case requires me to add a minimum of 1 while and 1 for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably do is breaking task into steps.

1. Get the input
2. satrt finding the prime numbers from 1 to the max

   1. create a list of already found prime numbers
   2. start a loop from 1 to max
   3. each iteration loop trough already found primes and perform `number % prime == 0`
   4. if none of numbers in prime numbers can fulfils the condition add number to the list
   5. if found number is greater or equal to min, save the index of it (startIndex).
3. print the input by iterating trough list from startIndex and printing the numbers

this workflow guarantees you will not consider multiplicant of two big prime numbers as prime number with better performance

Answer (score 0):

You missplaced your first statement, your while-loop is a little bit scary, but here your fix:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeN{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a,b;
a = sc.nextInt();
b = sc.nextInt();

for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){
 int count = 0;
 for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
  if(i%j == 0){
   count++;
  }
 }//count if equals 2 the prime numbers displayed
if(count == 2){
 System.out.println(i);a++;
}}}}
```